# Give examples of two non-isomorphic groups of order $n^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For each integer, $n > 7$, give examples of two non-isomorphic groups of order $n^2$.

Comment: I wonder why the questions asks for $n > 7$. That seems somewhat random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: For every $m$ there is a group of order $m$ (the cyclic one), so you have one group of order $n^2$ already. Now you just need another one, and a reason why it is not isomorphic to the one you already have. Think of $\mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_n$.

Answer (score 4):

How about $\mathbb{Z}/n^{2}\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. One is cyclic and the other not.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Think of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and direct product of this.